# Error while fetching a Bitbucket private repository

Tags: git, ssh, openshift, bitbucket

I'm using an Openshift 3 service. I'm trying to fetch data from my private Bitbucket repository. With using PuTTy for Windows I've created public and private SSH keys. The public key was loaded successfully as Access key into Bitbucket. Then I created a new secret through Openshift web console for my app, set it as SSH, loaded a private key and link this secret with builder service. After this I modified build configuration and set for my Bitbucket repo a secret with required name (choosen from dropdown box). But when I'm running a build process ("Start build") I'm getting an error "Fetch source failed". There are lines from my build log:

```
Cloning "ssh://bitbucket.org/<my_name>/<my_private_repo>.git" ...
error: build error: Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,104.192.143.3'  (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Is it possible to set up building process from web console ? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you added the second public key to bitbucket?

Comment: Can you tell me please what do you mean ? I added a public key as an Access key for required repository. Private key for this pair I used as a secret in Openshift.

Comment: You have created a second key pair in Openshift, right? Have you added the second public key to the access control of Bitbucket?

Comment: I created one pair of keys. Public and private. Public key was loaded as an Access key to Bitbucket for required repository and private key was used as a secret in Openshift. Is it what you mean ?

Comment: Have a read of the blog posts series starting with https://blog.openshift.com/private-git-repositories-part-1-best-practices/ if you haven't already. Also, how exactly did you add the secret to the build configuration? Did you use the ``oc set build-secret --source`` command or try and edit the build configuration yourself. When reading that blog posts series, ensure you read all posts and not just the one about BitBucket as earlier posts explain things in more detail.

Comment: Hi Graham. Thanks for your message. I've already read the last article in your series ("Private Git Repositories: Part 5 – Hosting Repositories on Bitbucket"). In whole articles you use command line tool. Is it possible to do the same actions with using web console ? Here is how I added a secret to build configuration. I open a last build, clicked 'Actions' button and choose 'Edit configuration'. Then in open page I checked 'Advanced options' for 'Source configuration' block and for 'Source secret' choose my secret from dropdown list.

Comment: I was able to fetch from gitlab private repo after few tries. the only issue, I am facing that openshift console do not provide a option to change initial deployment configuration, if you make a mistake.

I ended up deleting the deployment and create a fresh one. Would suggest that just retry in a fresh deployment. Your steps look correct. Just make sure that the keys are added correctly. Also, kindly check the if there is anything set (strict restriction on who can access the repo) at bitbucket level.

Comment: @gyan What of the 'initial deployment configuration' are you trying to change. Pretty well everything except the name of the deployment should be able to be changed.

Comment: @tvolf It is important to read all the blog posts, bit just the one on BitBucket as the earlier ones describe better some of the concepts, but using GitHub as the example. Only key details are given in the BitBucket one on assumption you read the earlier posts.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Through online web console, I was looking to change GIT configuration for a particular build, but I could not find the option in any of the edit screen. I even tried YML editing.

Comment: @gyan Thanks but I did all of this several times. Here is about Bitbucket repository. It's a new repository with default access rights. I did not change anything.

Comment: @gyan You would go to Builds->Builds->#appbuildname#->Configuration and then select Edit from the menu top right. The Git repository URL is there. Then at bottom select Show advanced options, and you can change the secret name to use.

Answer (score 2):

To have OpenShift v3 works with a private BitBucket repo, I used the following:

1. In OpenShift Web Console, create a project
2. Create a secret using your Bitbucket login information

   *** Web console version ***

   - From the web console, click on the project name in the breadcrumb and you will see the left side menu.
   - Select Resources > Secrets
   - Click Create Secret (top right)
   - Leave Basic Authentication
   - Enter a Secret name `bitbucket`
   - Enter your Bitbucket username and password
   - Click Create
   - Click Add to Project

   *** Command line version ***

   - Add a secret that stores your BitBucket login:

```
    $ oc login 
    This should select your project or if it did not, use the oc project PROJECTNAME

    $ oc secrets new-basicauth bitbucket --username=gregorifaroux -- password=MY_PASSWORD
    $ oc secrets link builder bitbucket
```

5. In the Web Console, I select Java & WilfFly
6. Put your Git URL:

```
    https://gregorifaroux@bitbucket.org/gregorifaroux/MYPRIVATEREPO.git
```

7. Click the Advance Options link, and then select the Secret Pull:

```
    bitbucket
```

And it should worked. If you already did a build, you can click Edit and then Advance Options to select the pull secret.

I could not get the Key to work following the different blog and documentation.

Comment: Hi Gregori. Do you mean you also tried to use SSH authentication for build making and this did not work ? I'm interesting in this method and would be nice do not use Openshift command line tool.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use the SSH authentication and it did not work. I followed multiple documents and blog, and it was still not working. I use the new-basicauth as a solution for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @tvolf I tested and you can use the Web console to create the secret before the build using the Bitbucket login information. Hope that helps.